# Is there any javascript or flash project can edit audio online?

Tags: javascript, flash, audio, editor

Is there any javascript or flash project can edit audio online?

I wish it can cut a part of audio, delete a part of audio, and add an audio to another.

Comment: [Check this](http://mp3cut.net/) and [this](https://audioeditor.filelab.com/app/).

Answer (score 0):

You may try the flash online [Audio Editor tool](http://advanced.aviary.com/tools/audio-editor) offered by Aviary Suite.

...

Note:You should not just post questions like in a general forum, support it with what you have tried..

Comment: Thank u loxxy! I just got an idea, and don't know is it possible to implement it, I will try it.

Comment: There's also http://www.indabamusic.com/labs http://www.clubcreate.com/  and http://soundation.com/

Answer (score 0):

this list of html5 audio libraries is quite comprehansive. http://www.html5libs.com/grids/g/audio/